# How to create a javascript functional 'class' so that I can access a 'method' from outside and inside the function

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

I am creating a function that handles a bunch of stuff around pagenating and sorting a table. It contains a key function that submits the db query and updates the display table.

I want to be able to access that inner function/method from both inside the function and also from outside on the object created.

```
testFunction = function() {
    keyMethod = function() {
        console.log('ya got me');
    };

    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        keyMethod();
    });

    keyMethod();
};

myTest = new testFunction();
myTest.keyMethod();


testFunction = function() {
    this.keyMethod = function() {
        console.log('ya got me');
    };

    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        // would have to use bind here which then messes up trying to
        // find the correct target etc.
        keyMethod();
    });

    this.keyMethod();
};

myTest= new DrawShape();
myTest.keyMethod();
```

Creating it the first way means that the keyMethod function is available everywhere within the testFunction but I cant call it from outside.

Creating it the second way means I can do myTest.keyMethod but I then cant call it from within an inner function without using bind everywhere.

Is there a better way..?

Comment: Those are pretty much the only two options. You may want to elaborate on that target-bind issue and we may be able to suggest you something.

Comment: target-bind issue, say I add the event to an a tag that has some txt/image/icon in it. Usually I would do something like this.getAttribute('blah') to get something from the a tag. If I bind this to the event function i cant do that and e.target will point to the contents of the a tag, ie what they clicked and bubbled up to the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the function provided as callback with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) or use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function first like you already said.

```js
testFunction = function() {
    this.keyMethod = function() {
        console.log('ya got me');
    };

    // Replace callback by simply providing the function to call.
    // This works as long as you don't use the `this` keyword inside the
    // provided function.
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', this.keyMethod);

    // If your callback method does use the `this` keyword you can either use an
    // arrow function or bind the function up front.
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', event => this.keyMethod());
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', this.keyMethod.bind(this));

    this.keyMethod();
};

console.log("constructor output:");
myTest = new testFunction();
console.log(".keyMethod() output:");
myTest.keyMethod();
console.log("click event output:");
```

```html
<button id="test">test</button>
```